# CSS Flexbox with Margin Spacing Causing Unwanted Stretch of Items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a flexbox. There are 4 circles that are 25% width of the parent element. I added margin between the items but now the circles "stretch" because of my padding %. I'd like to keep the padding as a % to maintain an aspect ratio I require. But when I add margin to create spacing between the items stretch.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.items>* {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.items>*:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**The shape I want, but not the spacing:**

[image: With margin spacing:]

**The spacing I want, but not the shape:**

[image]

Also, the reason I use margin is to have equal spacing all around the element in the case there are rows of elements.

How do I get the spacing and shape I want together?

Comment: I'll put your example in a code snippet and it works....Try to add `box-sizing:border-box;`. [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not remove the margin from the `:after` pseudo element and use padding on the main element? (also added box-sizing on main element):

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.items>* {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items>*:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer. I was trying to work with border-box but for some reason I was putting it in the wrong style. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Insert a `gap` in your flex element, then remove the padding and margin for the pseudoelement (`::after`) and use `aspect-ratio`

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.items > * {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.items > *::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but I need the elements to be able to wrap.

Comment: So set wrap instead